# If $\;\lim_{x\to b^-} g(x)=\infty\;,\;g(x)>0\;\forall x\in[a,b)$ and $f$ is bounded on $[a,b)$, must it be that $\lim_{x\to b^-}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> If $\;\lim\limits_{x\to b^-} g(x)=\infty\;,\;g(x)>0\;\forall x\in[a,b)$ and $f$ is bounded on $[a,b)$, must it be that $\lim\limits_{x\to b^-}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0\;?$

Is my proof correct?

*Proof.* Since $f$ is bounded on $[a,b)$, $\exists L > 0$ s.t.
$$-L\leqslant f(x)\leqslant L\quad\quad\forall x\in [a,b)\;.$$
Then
$$-\frac L{g(x)}\leqslant\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\leqslant\frac L{g(x)} \quad\quad\forall x\in [a,b)\;,$$
hence ,
$$-\lim_{x\to b^{-}}\frac{L}{g(x)}\leqslant\lim_{x\to b^{-}}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\leqslant\lim_{x\to b^{-}}\frac{L}{g(x)}$$
$$0\leqslant\lim_{x\to b^{-}}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\leqslant0\implies\lim_{x\to b^{-}} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0.$$

Comment: You do not need that $\,f\,$ is continuous, it is sufficient that it is bounded on $\,\big[a,b\big)\;.$

Comment: I was trying to use this as a lemma for a bigger proof so I had that written out

Comment: Anyway you do not need continuity to prove the lemma.

Comment: Now, your proof looks better.

Comment: Actually you could prove your lemma without the hypothesis $\,g(x)>0\;\forall x\in [a,b)\,$ because you know that $\,\lim\limits_{x\to b^-}g(x)=\infty\,$ implies that there exists $\,c\in(a,b)\,$ such that $\,g(x)>0\,$ for all $\,x\in[c,b)\,.$

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following more general lemma :

> If $\lim\limits_{x\to b^-} \big|g(x)\big|=\infty\;$ and $f$ is bounded on $[a,b)\;,\;$ then $\lim\limits_{x\to b^-}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0\;.$

*Proof.* Since $f$ is bounded on $[a,b)\,$, $\,\exists L>0\,$ such that
$$\big|f(x)\big|\leqslant L\quad\quad\forall x\in [a,b)\;.$$

Since $\lim\limits_{x\to b^-} \big|g(x)\big|=\infty\;,\;$ there exists $\,c\in(a,b)\,$ such that

$$\big|g(x)\big|\ne0\quad\quad\forall x\in [c,b)\;.$$

Then
$$0\leqslant\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|\leqslant\frac L{\left|g(x)\right|}\quad\quad\forall x\in [c,b)\;\;,$$
hence ,
$$0\leqslant\lim_{x\to b^{-}}\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|\leqslant\lim_{x\to b^{-}}\frac{L}{\left|g(x)\right|}\;\;,$$
$$0\leqslant\lim_{x\to b^{-}}\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|\leqslant0\;\;,$$
$$\lim_{x\to b^{-}}\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right|=0\;\;\implies\;\;\lim_{x\to b^{-}}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0\;.$$